# Setting up new facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

While setting up the Facebook SDK. You need to get the KeyHash.
I typed the following code to get the keyhash

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and got the error shown in the screenshot below. I use windows7 64bit.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

From what it looks like windows dos command prompt does not come standard with a keytool command. I typed this into my linux terminal and it found the command, so I would suggest either downloading and installing the windows equivalent of keytool or finding out if windows has a native method that supports these features. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

if you are running it in windows, 
first, cd to your (java) jdk 1.6/1.7 folder in program files\java then cd bin
second, if you get a message that path cannot be resolved, type a complete path to your keystore file